# ArrayList Introducir datos de personas por pantalla y mostrar las personas Introducidas

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola muy buenas tengo un problema con mi codigo y llevo 2 dias sin poder acabarlo mi problema es que tengo un scanner donde voy introduciendo los datos de las personas (Nombre, apellido, edad etc....) estos datos se amacenan en sets que previamente he creado en la clase de Personas y haciendo un extends de otra clase que se llama personas ricas, creo el array list añadiendolo los datos introducido anteriormente nombre apellido etc... y cuando voy a dar de alta 2 personas solo me sale la persona que he dado de alta por ultima vez no me salen las dos personas dadas de alta Envio el codigo:

```
public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <PersonaRica> gente = new ArrayList<PersonaRica>();
         boolean salir = false;
         Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         PersonaRica p1 = new PersonaRica();
         int opcion;




 while (!salir){ 
             System.out.println("1.- Insertar una Persona");   
             System.out.println("2.- Eliminar una Persona"); 
             System.out.println("3.- Mostrar Personas ");
             System.out.println("4.- Salir ");



             System.out.println("[Indicame la Funcion]:");
             opcion = Scan.nextInt();

                 switch (opcion) {       
                     case 1:
                         // Nombre de la persona
                          System.out.println("Nombre del alumno: ");
                          String nombre = Scan.next();

                          System.out.println("Apellido: ");
                          String apellidos = Scan.next();


                          System.out.println("Año de nacimiento: ");
                          int anynacimiento = Scan.nextInt();


                          System.out.println("Edad: ");
                          int edad = Scan.nextInt();


                          System.out.println("Dinero: ");
                          int dinero = Scan.nextInt();


                          System.out.println("Provincia: ");
                          String provincia = Scan.next();


                          System.out.println("Ciudad: ");
                          String ciudad = Scan.next();


                          System.out.println("DNI: ");
                          String dni = Scan.next();



                          //Llamamos a a los sets para ir introduciendo los valores.
                          p1.setNombre(nombre);
                          p1.setApellidos(apellidos);
                          p1.setAnyoNacimiento(anynacimiento);
                          p1.setEdad(edad);
                          p1.setDinero(dinero);
                          p1.setProvincia(provincia);
                          p1.setCiudad(ciudad);
                          p1.setDni(dni);
                          gente.add(p1);

                          System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta correctamente!");
                          break;

                     case 2:
                         String nombre1;


                         System.out.println("El Nombre ha eliminar: ");
                         nombre1 = Scan.next();

                         for (Persona persona: gente) {
                             if(p1.getNombre().equals(nombre1)){             
                                     gente.remove(p1);
                                     System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente!");

                                  }else {

                                      System.out.print("No se ha encontrado la persona.....");                                
                                  }
                             }
                         break;
                     case 3:

                        //Para mostrar la Persona que deseas.

                         for (int i = 0; i < gente.size(); i++) {
                                 System.out.println("Persona: " + gente.get(i).getNombre());
                                 break;
                             }

                          break;

                      case 4:
                        salir = true;
                        System.out.println("\033[31mGracias por utilizar el programa!");
                        break;
                 }  
                 }



    }



}
```

Comment: Hola @KratosDofus. Por favor, pega el código en formato texto y no en imagen ya que así no lo podemos copiar para probarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: Revisa tu código.Solo estás creando una instancia de `PersonaRica`(p1)....

Comment: Claro poque en teoria y pienso yo que lo que me pasa es que cuando doy de alta a una persona se añade en el array pero cuando añado otra se me sobreescribe y no me hace como un salta.

Comment: No, no se te sobreescribe. El problema es que estás añadiendo siempre la misma instancia.Si solo creas una instancia de una clase, la segunda vez que introduces datos lo que estás haciendo es modificando los datos de esa instancia, no creando una nueva. Creo que deberías repasar un poco el concepto de instancia. A parte de eso, tienes varios errores en tu código, pero ese concretamente podrás resolverlo si en cada iteración añades `p1 = new PersonaRica()`...

Comment: Yo hice un ejercicio similar y añadi un contador que cada vez que hiciera una alta de una persona nueva me sumara una nueva alta, pero lo hice con array y no se hacerlo con arraylist.

Comment: Pikoh tiene razón, en mi respuesta he añadido la explicación de como gestionar la nueva instacia (también he corregido el error que te impide borrar `PersonaRica` de tu `ArrayList`(agente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explicación**

No te aparece ya que en el `for` que tienes para mostrar las personas (dentro del `case 3`):

```
 //Para mostrar la Persona que deseas.
     case 3:
     for (int i = 0; i < gente.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println("Persona: " + gente.get(i).getNombre());
          break;
     }

     break;
```

Estás realizando un `break` (dentro del bucle), con lo cual, tu bucle `for` solo se ejecuta una vez (realiza una sola iteración como máximo, y ningúna como mínimo).

**¿Por qué?**

Cuando el `ArrayList`(gente) tenga uno o más datos, el bucle `for` se realizará una sola vez(**siempre**), ya que al llegar al `break`, se detiene el bucle for y sigue con el resto del código. Cuando el `ArrayList`(gente) no tenga datos, el bucle `for` no se realizara ningúna vez (lo cual es correcto).

**Error al añadir nuevas 'PersonaRica` al Arraylist**

También fijate que en la línea donde estas definiendo `PersonaRica`(p1) y la añades en el ArrayList:

```
p1.setNombre(nombre);
p1.setApellidos(apellidos);
p1.setAnyoNacimiento(anynacimiento);
p1.setEdad(edad);
p1.setDinero(dinero);
p1.setProvincia(provincia);
p1.setCiudad(ciudad);
p1.setDni(dni);
gente.add(p1);
```

Siempre estas añadiendo `p1` (que es una variable global de tu clase), con lo cual, siempre estas añadiendo la misma persona, puedes pensar que le estas cambiando las caracteristicas a `p1` y luego añadiendolo al `ArrayList`(gente), pero al modificar `p1`, estas modificando todas las personas que contiene tu `ArrayList`(gente), ya que todas apuntan a la misma `PersonaRica`.

**¿Cómo solucionas este problema?**

Antes de añadir una `PersonaRica` a tu `ArrayList`(gente), especificas que p1 es una nueva persona, es decir:

```
p1 = new PersonaRica(); //Creas una nueva instancia de PersonaRica
p1.setNombre(nombre);
p1.setApellidos(apellidos);
p1.setAnyoNacimiento(anynacimiento);
p1.setEdad(edad);
p1.setDinero(dinero);
p1.setProvincia(provincia);
p1.setCiudad(ciudad);
p1.setDni(dni);
gente.add(p1);
```

**Error al borrar personas**

No puedes borrar `PersonaRicas` de tu `ArrayList`(agente) ya que cuando iteras sobre el `ArrayList`(agente), en el bucle `for` especificas que la variable local que se va a crear es `persona`: `for (Persona persona: gente)`, sin embargo, a la hora de hacer las comparaciones y eliminar una persona, utilizas `p1`.

El código pasaría de:

```
case 2:
String nombre1;
System.out.println("El Nombre ha eliminar: ");
nombre1 = Scan.next();

for (Persona persona: gente) {
    if(p1.getNombre().equals(nombre1)){             
          gente.remove(p1);
          System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente!");
    }else {
          System.out.print("No se ha encontrado la persona.....");                                
    }
}
break;
```

a:

```
case 2:
String nombre1;
System.out.println("El Nombre ha eliminar: ");
nombre1 = Scan.next();

for (Persona persona: gente) {
    if(persona.getNombre().equals(nombre1)){             
          gente.remove(persona);
          System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente!");
    }else {
          System.out.print("No se ha encontrado la persona.....");                                
    }
}
break;
```